# Como ver perfil de usuarios?

Tags: php, jquery, html5, mysqli

Veran tengo un textbox autocomplete,el cual se autocompleta cuando voy escribiendo desde una base de datos(Mysql). Bien lo quiero que me ayuden es como seleccionar el ID de esos elementos e ir al perfil de cada usuario que yo seleccione.

PD:
Me dicen que tengo que crear otra pagina que sea para los perfiles de usuarios que yo quiera ver.Aparte del mio.Es verdad?

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="busquedas" name="buscar" placeholder="Busca a 
alguien">             
<div id="nameList"></div>
```

**PHP**

```
  <?php

include("conexion.php");

 if(isset($_POST['query']))
 {

 $output = '';
 $query = "SELECT * FROM personas WHERE nombre LIKE '%". 
 $_POST['query']."%'";
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
 $output = '<ul class="list-unstyled">';

 if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 )
 {

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {

      $output .= '<li><a href="#">'.$row['nombre'].''.$row['apellido'].'</a>
      </li>';
   }
  }

   else
     {
    $output .= '<li>Not found</li>';
     }

     $output .= '</ul>';
     echo $output;
         }

  ?>
```

**JQuery**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
 $('#busquedas').keyup(function(){

 var query = $(this).val();
 if(query != '')
 {
 $.ajax({

     url:"usuarios.php",
     method:"POST",
     data:{query:query},
     success:function(data)
     {
          $('#nameList').fadeIn();
          $('#nameList').html(data);
      }
    });
  }
    });

     $(document).on('click', '#nameList ul li', function(){

   $('#busquedas').val($(this).text());
    $('#nameList').fadeOut(); 
     });

  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solución
**
PD:La solucion era :

```
/*_el cual recoge el Id enviado a traves de la url_*/
$GetId = $_GET['id']; 

/*_Para hacer la seleccion de los datos segun el ID_*/
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM personas WHERE Id = '$GetId'";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Y LUEGO RECOGER O IMPRIMIR LOS DATOS,PERO CLARO TODO ESE CODIGO VA EN LA PAGINA USUARIO.PHP(de los usuarios).
**

```
     <?php

        echo "mi Codigo es :".$GetId."<br>";
        echo "Mi nombre es :".$row['nombre']."<br>";
        echo "Mi apellido es :".$row['apellido']."<br>";
        echo "Mi correo es :".$row['correo']."<br>";
        echo "Mi clave es :".$row['password']."<br>";

        ?>
```

**

CODIGO COMPLETO
**

HTML
**

```
 <input type="text" id="busquedas" name="buscar" placeholder="Busca a 
alguien">             
 <div id="nameList"></div>
```

**

PHP
**

```
 <?php

 include("conexion.php");

 if(isset($_POST['query']))
 {

 $output = '';
 $query = "SELECT * FROM personas WHERE nombre LIKE '%".  
    $_POST['query']."%'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$output = '<ul class="list-unstyled">';

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 )
{

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {

          $output .= '<li><a href="perfil2.php? id='.$row['Id'].'">'.$row['nombre'].' '.$row['apellido'].'</a></li>';
    }
}
else
{
     $output .= '<li>Not found</li>';
}

$output .= '</ul>';
echo $output;
   }

   ?>
```

**

JQuery
**

```
  $(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('#busquedas').keyup(function(){

 var query = $(this).val();
 if(query != '')
 {
 $.ajax({

     url:"usuarios.php",
     method:"POST",
     data:{query:query},
     success:function(data)
     {
          $('#nameList').fadeIn();
          $('#nameList').html(data);
     }
 });
}
    });

     $(document).on('click', '#nameList ul li', function(){

  $('#busquedas').val($(this).text());
  $('#nameList').fadeOut(); 
   });

   });
```

**

usuario.php(perfil destino)
**

```
<?php
 session_start();

 include("usuarios.php");

 $GetId = $_GET['id'];

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM personas WHERE Id = '$GetId'";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

  ?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

</head>
<body>
<?php

        echo "mi Codigo es :".$GetId."<br>";
        echo "Mi nombre es :".$row['nombre']."<br>";
        echo "Mi apellido es :".$row['apellido']."<br>";
        echo "Mi correo es :".$row['correo']."<br>";
        echo "Mi clave es :".$row['password']."<br>";

        ?>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Saludos, es correcto al afirmación debes crear una pagina perfil, esta debe ser reutilizada sin necesidad de crear varias páginas de perfil por usuario, solo deberás pasarle el identificador del usuario seleccionado o bien el identificador de tu usuario.

En el fragmento de código deberás adicionar:

```
$output .= '<li><a href="perfil.php?id=23">'.$row['nombre'].''.$row['apellido'].'</a> </li>';
```

Donde: id=**23**  es el identificador de cada usuario.